# Selective static html export of pages in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am working on a NextJS project where we are planning to do static HTML export of pages as described [here](https://nextjs.org/docs#static-html-export).

Here, Is the scenario I want to have worked:

Say we have already statically generated the following pages.

about/product1

about/product2

about/product3

During the course of the day, the availability of product1 has changed. Is there a way to only do a static export of about/product1 without touching the other pages which have been previously exported.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your example, you should follow these steps:

### Step 1

Create a configuration file to set up a custom [`exportMap`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/exportPathMap):

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  exportPathMap: async function(
    defaultPathMap,
    { dev, dir, outDir, distDir, buildId }
  ) {
    return {
      // only include the pages that you want to export
      'about/product1': { page: 'about/product1' },
    }
  },
}
```

### Step 2

Build and export **making sure to set a different output folder**. For instance, if your build and export script is called `bexport` and you want to name your new export folder as "out2" you would use:

```
yarn bexport -o out2
```

**Warning:** if you don't specify a different output folder, only `about/product1` will be reexported to the original output folder, but `about/product2` and `about/product3` would be erased because they're not included in the current `exportMap` setup.

### Step 3

Move the reexported file to the folder that contains all the exported pages to overwrite the previous version of `about/product1`:

```
mv out2/about/product1.html out/about/
```